# How do I respond to screen orientation changes when using GetX in a Flutter App?

Tags: android, flutter, orientation, screen-orientation, flutter-getx

How do I respond to screen orientation changes when using GetX in a Flutter App?

`OrientationBuilder` does not work, even if wrapped inside Obs and using `Get.context.isLandscape` etc.

In a test app I have tried the following to no avail:

```dart
class Home extends GetView<StoreController> {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key) {
    Get.put(StoreController());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Orientation Test"),

        // Does not work
        leading: OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (ctx, or) {
            return Get.context?.isLandscape ?? false 
                ? const Icon(Icons.menu) 
                : const Icon(Icons.add);
          },
        ),

        // Does not work
        leading: OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (ctx, orientation) {
            return orientation == Orientation.landscape
                ? const Icon(Icons.menu)
                : const Icon(Icons.add);
          },
        ),

        // Does not work (error: improper use of Obs())
        leading: Obx(() {
          //controller.counter.value++;
          return OrientationBuilder(
            builder: (ctx, orientation) {
              return orientation == Orientation.landscape 
                  ? const Icon(Icons.menu) 
                  : const Icon(Icons.add);
            },
          );
        }),


      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
            Obx(() => Text('${controller.counter.value}', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: controller.incCounter, tooltip: 'Increment', child: const Icon(Icons.add)),
    );
  }
}
```

Simple Controller:

```dart
class StoreController extends GetxController {
  final counter = 0.obs;

  void incCounter() {
    counter.value++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm currently testing on an Android emulator. The app will run on all platforms in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it in the Following way:

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  MyClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyClass> createState() => _MyClassState();
  }

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {
  RxBool isLandscape = false.obs;          // To check the orientation
  ....
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    isLandscape.value = context.isLandscape;  // to Update the value continuously on any change.
    return Scaffold(
      body: allImages(),
    }
  }

Obx allImages() => Obx(() => GridView.builder(
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: isLandscape.value ? 5 : 2)   // To Update the UI
    ....
    ));
```

Comment: One of the features of GetX is to use Stateless Widgets so your answer is a non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetResponsiveView` instead of `GetView`. This will give you access to different layout extensions such as `screen`.

You then have different options to do what you want to do. One is to use the `mobile()`, `phone()`, `tablet()` and `desktop()` overrides but you can also do that using the `builder()` method.

```
class HomeView extends GetResponsiveView< StoreController > {
          HomeView({Key? key})
              : super(
                  key: key,
                  alwaysUseBuilder: false, // This is needed to use the mobile(), phone(), tablet() and desktop() overrides
                );
        
          @override
          Widget? phone() => const HomePhoneView();
        
          @override
          Widget? tablet() => screen.context.isLandscape
              ? const HomeDesktopView()
              : const HomeTabletView();
        
          @override
          Widget? desktop() => const HomeDesktopView();
        }
```